# Connecting a web client to a c++ server with TCP

Tags: node.js, tcp, socket.io, tcpclient

i wrote a simple C++ Server which is waiting for clients.

I want users to be able to connect to this client by opening a webpage without installing anything. So the only thing that comes to my mind is using Javascript. Since the server needs to react in realtime later on ( performance is an issue ) sending data with POST/GET is not wanted.

Is this possible with Node.js or Socket.io ? I am trying to find a good example but i only find node.js servers. And when i open a socket with

```
  var socket = io.connect('localhost:25003');
```

it is sending weird data.

Does anyone have a simple example with a javascript client that can connect to anything and send raw data?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do plain TCP from browsers (unless you're writing a browser addon/extension or using something like a Java applet or a Flash bridge possibly). Socket.IO always uses HTTP. However those HTTP connections can then be upgraded to WebSockets or other protocols, depending on what the browser and/or Internet connection supports.

The "weird data" you're seeing is probably an HTTP message.

Comment: OK this seems to be obvious if i think about it. The question is now, can i use socket.io on the client side and still use c++ on the server side? Will Websocket librarys(on the c++ side) be enough or do i need to use "raw" websockets on the client side to achieve this?

Comment: You specifically would need a socket.io C++ library since socket.io has its own protocol on top of websockets, long polling, etc. As far as I know, there is no server portion of this for C++, only client libraries.

Comment: I found that socket.io client in c++ with QT earlier but no server. So maybe i should use Websockets directly or even use node.js as a bridge to send it to my c++ server? Can you think of any alternative on connecting a web client to a c++ server?